# Why does the US law seem to conflict with the Kigali Amendment on phasing out R-32 refrigerants?

Tags: united-states

The Kigali amendment to the Montreal Protocol states that R-32 (HFC-32) should be phased out of use for certain countries like the US significantly in the next decade. Here's the text: https://treaties.un.org/doc/Treaties/2016/10/20161015%2003-23%20PM/Ch_XXVII-2.f-English%20and%20French.pdf

- Page 32 has HFC-32 in Annex F
- Page 26 references Annex F

In the following document by the EPA, they say "The AIM Act directs EPA to phase down the production and consumption of HFCs by 85% by 2036. The U.S. phasedown is consistent with the schedule in the Kigali Amendment to the Montreal Protocol"

https://www.epa.gov/system/files/documents/2022-12/TT%20Rule%20NPRM%20Fact%20Sheet%20Final.pdf

Yet, in that same article, they point out that they are limiting the GPW (greenhouse warming potential) to 700 -- a number R-32 just barely sits below.

These statements seem contradictory. In summary:

- The Kigali agreement says R-32 needs to be phased out
- The EPA says the AIM act is consistent with the Kigali agreement
- The AIM act does not phase out R-32

What might I be misunderstanding?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://politics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch this question concerns the interpretation of legal texts, in particular whether a specific law is consistent with a specific international agreement, and furthermore asks for an analysis of a government action in the context of those legal texts.  It is certainly on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the unit of measurement is in CO2 equivalents. From the Amendment:

"Each Party shall ensure that for the twelve-month period commencing on 1 January 2019,
and in each twelve-month period thereafter, its calculated level of consumption of the
controlled substances in Annex F, **expressed in CO2 equivalents**, does not exceed the
percentage, set out for the respective range of years specified in subparagraphs (a) to (e)
below, of the annual average of its calculated levels of consumption of Annex F controlled
substances for the years 2011, 2012 and 2013,"

So it's likely that the EPA has determined that R-32 (which has ~25% of the GWP of other common refrigerants) is fine in a variety of use cases to ultimately get to an 85% CO2e reduction by 2036, compared to the average of 2011/2012/2013.